# Custom button with a selection

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I don't know if this has been asked before. I am going to be building a calculator for my dad. He asked me if there is any way to have customization with the buttons.

I have not done any code yet. I plan on trying a few things. My research has come up with nothing.

This is what I am trying to accomplish, I have a feeling it breaks the android studio law of coding. This is the concept:

Imagine the calculator. You have 8 blank buttons above the numbers. Those buttons ordinarily have the functions such as percent and sqrt.,..etc.

I have been asked if it's possible can he just hold the button and change those functions at will.

So the question at hand is. Can I do if statements to change the symbol and the code for a particular button when long pressed?

The concept of the calculator would be in portrait mode he can customize the buttons to the functions he uses without having to turn the calculator in landscape mode?

So in theory you have a long press which would bring up a selector. He can select any math function and based on that function the symbol and code would change and the button will work properly to the new selection?

I was going to to build the calculator as a standard. But was also wondering myself if this is possible. I know the buttons serve as a one function but in coding anything is possible.

Any help or advice would be appreciated. If this can be done it opens new possibilities to app features to only show what you want and not a predefined controls.

*******once I try a few codes I will edit question to better see the issue and what I am trying to do.

Comment: Sure it's possible, and this is nowhere near "breaking the android studio law of coding". It sounds like a pretty normal idea. But the question as it is now is way too broad. Just go ahead and try make it and if problems arise you could ask more specific questions instead

Comment: It's programming. You can do anything the hardware is capable of within whatever security restraints the OS has, which of course doesn't apply to button behavior.

Comment: @IvoBeckers I know it's possible. I just never done it before. I never seen a calculator with that feature to customize the button. So I know it's possible it's just trying to get the correct sequence. I hardly ask questions on here and I have recently migrated to kotlin. I do a lot on windows WPF, but never really done anything on Kotlin. So it's a learning curve.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I have an app I am pushing to Google play this week and that was one of the features I had thought about in my weather app. But dad said he needs a good calculator with the functions he uses. So this question was brought up. I never see these customized controls in apps. So I wonder if it's a useful feature or no one doesn't do them

Comment: Seems like a good feature for a calculator. Long press isn't often recommended for mobile apps because discoverability can be an issue, but it can be a power-user feature. The strategy I would use is create an enum class that defines a button icon ID and a function. Give every customizable button unique ID and a default value of the enum that you can persist to disk. When one of these buttons is long-pressed, you show a drop-down menu of the enum so it's attached enum value can be changed.

Comment: @Tenfour04 the biggest thing is dad only uses certain functions. The functions he uses he has to turn the phone in landscape. So he said he would be tickled if he had a calculator to customize the buttons to what he uses most in portrait then the other buttons in landscape change to the functions not used. So that's the biggest issue. If sin is used in portrait then sin in landscape should be replaced with another function. That's what I am trying to figure out.

Comment: It's straight-forward logic. When one button changes, you check the other buttons and change them as necessary automatically. You just need to plan out the logic on paper and then implement it.

Comment: @Tenfour04 that what I am doing now is paper drawing board and getting the code wrote down long hand. Then try it on the actual code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. OnLongPress show a dialog with the option you want and change the button text according to selected option.
2. On Onclick check the button text and call function according to the text

Comment: That's what I was thinking. But I was under the assumption that I would have to code all the functions (sqrt, percent..etc.) to each button.

Comment: no button will work according to text